# TinyMCE dialog.css not loading in image popup, throws 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce, loading

When the image icon is clicked and the Image popup starts, the JS works but the CSS (`dialog.css`) fails to load and there is a `404` due to an incorrect URL being used by the TinyMCE JS.

I am loading tinyMCE with advanced theme from the path:

```
"/local/scripts/admin/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"
```

The editor works fine but when I try to load the image popup the dialog.css does not load and Firebug reports a `404`.

The popup code is trying to load the dialog.css relative to the page in which the tinyMCE editor is loaded (in this case "/schools") so the final URL called by the image popup code that returns the `404` is:

```
https://[domain name]/schools/themes/advanced/skins/default/dialog.css
```

instead of
`https://[domain name]/local/scripts/admin/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/dialog.css`

I am doing an `init()` with `tinyMCE.baseURL='/local/scripts/admin/tiny_mce';` and have tried permutations including the full hostname and path, trailing slashes etc. but no success.
Also have tried some of the `document_base_url` and `relative_urls` config properties as well.

Any ideas why the `dialog.css` is not loading ?

Many thanks in advance for assistance.
`TinyMCE 3.4.9` (non-jQuery version)

Comment: try `tinyMCE.baseURL = "/schools"`

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with the pop-ups not recognizing or using the base_url for the dialog.css. I have tried many variations of the hostname and combinations of baseURL/document_base_url/relative_urls as well... no success.

I came up with a work around which uses the 'popup_css_add'.

The browser still misses the initial dialog.css call but then finds the 'popup_css_add' call.

```
tinyMCE.init({
  popup_css_add : '/local/scripts/admin/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/dialog.css'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try tinyMCE.baseURL = "/schools" – @UnLoCo suggested Aug 9 at 1:12